# Remove the "basics" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, clean-up

Currently, there are 167 questions tagged [basics](/questions/tagged/basics) on Stack Overflow. This tag feels very meta-y to me, and doesn't seem to communicate much useful information, other than *"treat me nice, I'm a noob!"* I suggest that it be removed.

Comment: I'm impressed by the fact that 10 people are following that tag.

Comment: @RD01: Perhaps people looking for easy questions to answer?  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: This is the right answer to so much more than just this question.